# Simple addition

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I add the following data in a simpler way.

I have `Data.map(data => data.a.x + data.a.y)`

I wanted to add it in a simple way as `Data.map(data => data.a(x+y))`.

But it doesn't seem to be a correct way, Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: can you also post `Data`

Comment: You can destructure, but that'd make it less readable, IMO your current code is fine

Comment: Please post your `Data` JSON

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't. the syntax is wrong. but what you can do is to destructure the object itself

```
const dt = data.map(({ a }) => a.x + a.y)
```

or you can go further like,

```
const dd = data.map(({ a: { x, y } }) => x + y)
```

but as you see, the readability is poor and not recommended for the second syntax. so, if you do destructure, please stop at the first sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using destructuring:

```js
var Data = [{
  a: {
    x: 10,
    y: 5
  }
}];

var res = Data.map(({a:{x, y}}) => x + y);
console.log(res);
```